# Xero API invalid OrgId

Tags: .net-core, xero-api

Working with [Xero API](https://app.xero.com/)

Authorization callback returns `org`, which [should correspond](https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/3268204) `Organisation`'s [`ShortCode`](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/organisation) for which Xero user allowed access.

In callback `org` value is `BFtWATeLda24OXh2Yv-FLG` but `Organisation`'s `ShortCode` is `!hvw0y`, which obviously does not match.

Other possible field that could be matched

- `OrganisationId` - `29e0fd2c-15da-409e-8462-1ac28b9f8f55` **no match**
- `ApiKey` - `QIBVL4B2BBDNE5WBADGFHZEQYR6SXM` **no match**

I wonder how can i link value `org` callback parameter to `Organisation` in Xero.

*Using [Xero API .NET Core client](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net)*

Answer (score 1):

Is it named the org_muid? If so, that value returned in the oauth call is actually a one way mapping of the OrganisationID. It's a legacy property from before the OrganisationID was returned from the organisation endpoint that is still returned as the removal of it could cause breaking changes for those who use it as the identifier in their token databases.

Comment: no, not `org_muid`. 3 parameters are returned into a callback, `org`, `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`

Comment: I've taken a look now and have confirmed that the value returned in the oauth callback for the org parameter is the same as the org_muid value returned when receiving an access token (swapping the authorised request token for an access token)

Comment: do you know how can i get organisation details based on `org_muid` ?

Comment: You can't unfortunately. As I said, it's a legacy property returned only on those oauth requests. I assume they have been used by developers in the past as a way to identify a request token in a data store that has been swapped for an access token (so that the request token can be removed) but that's also just speculation

Comment: very bad. then how can i know for which organisation i have gained access, if user has multiple organisations ?

Comment: Make a request against the [Organisation endpoint](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/organisation) using the access token you just received. The access token gives you access to only the organisation the user authorised.